# Closures as optional function arguments in Rust

Tags: closures, rust, argument-passing, optional-parameters, option-type

Is it possible to have closures as *optional* arguments in functions?

I need something like this (in pseudocode):

```
fn function(x: int, optional expr |int| -> int) -> int
```

and usage would be something like this:

```
// just the mandatory argument
n = function(z);
```

or optionally:

```
// passed closure would be called inside the function
n = function(z, |x| x * x);
```

I just cant grasp the correct syntax if its even possible (*would appreciate full example with correct match expressions*).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Optional parameters are in the [wish list](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/323), but they aren't in the language yet, AFAIK.

What you obviously can do is making two functions

```
fn function(x: int) -> int {function_with_expr (x, |n|n*n)}
fn function_with_expr(x: int, expr: |int| -> int) -> int
```

That's the approach used in the standard library.

---

You can also pass a special trait into the function, like passing [ToSocketAddr](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/trait.ToSocketAddrs.html) into [bind](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.TcpListener.html#method.bind), and then you might implement that trait for various tuple types. I'm not sure if passing the closure through the tuple will be as simple as passing it directly, though.